# Can I show an image in a HoverProvider?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am new to vscode extension development so not sure best places to look for help. I want to hover over a word, and if that word matches the name in our icon directory, show a hover with that image. My first try was to use markdown to show the svg image from the web, but I believe that is not allowed for security that code could be executed. Can I show an svg in the markdown in a vscode.Hover? I can either include the svgs in the extension, or expect that the developer has already installed the npm package with the files into the workspace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is actually quite rich support for content and styling in `MarkdownString` in hovers.

You can use `svg's` directly this way:

```js
const icon = new vscode.MarkdownString('<img src="icon.svg"/>');
icon.baseUri = vscode.Uri.file(path.join(context.extensionPath, 'images', path.sep));
```

The `baseUri` property is crucial.  Here it gets the svgs from an `images` folder.

In the below I added the `png` images to an extension `images` folder.  You can detect what word is hovered and load the corresponding icon.

Below is testing in a plaintext file:

```js
// with this require/import
const path = require('path');

// ...

let disposable4 = vscode.languages.registerHoverProvider('plaintext', {
  provideHover(document, position) {

    // one way to find the current hovered word
    // note that what is a 'word' is languaged-defined and typically does not include hyphens
    // const word = document.getText(document.getWordRangeAtPosition(position));
    // first check if there is an icon for the hovered word, if not return undefined
    // glob the images folder and find 'icon'.svg
    // const icon = new vscode.MarkdownString(`<img src="${word}.svg"/>`);
  
    // dimensions not necessary if you aren't changing them
    const content = new vscode.MarkdownString(`<img src="favicon144.png" width=144 height=144/>`);

    content.appendMarkdown(`$(zap)`);  // notice the little "zap" icon in the hover

    content.supportHtml = true;

    content.isTrusted = true;

    content.supportThemeIcons = true;  // to supports codicons
    
    // baseUri was necessary, full path in the img src did not work
    // with your icons stroed in the 'images' directory
    content.baseUri = vscode.Uri.file(path.join(context.extensionPath, 'images', path.sep));            

    return new vscode.Hover(content, new vscode.Range(position, position));
  }
});
```

[image: add an image to a hover pop-up]

Comment: I added a build script to convert the svg to png using sharp. This works when I'm developing the extension. When I go to package it and install it locally, the images are broken. My subfolder is called images and my source code is in src.  When I examine the vsix, I see the files in there. But the javascript that uses it has been moved to out folder. Do I have to compensate for move in publishing? What best practices should I follow here?

Comment: What `baseUri` are you using when you publish?  I would try `context.extensionUri`.

Comment: I think I got it working with: `content.baseUri = vscode.Uri.file(path.join(context.extensionPath, 'images', '\\'));`  with the icons stored in the `images` directory obviously.  Didn't work without that last double backslash.  I can't test on a Mac though.  Let me know if it works for you and I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: That last comment is the right answer!  Thank you!

Comment: Great, a slight improvement to use `path.sep`.  Please consider accepting the answer.  Thank you.

Comment: I found a way to use `svg` files directly and modified the answer to show that.

Answer (score 0):

There's only very limited Markdown support in hover items and images are not supported there at all, as far as I know.